# Run a remove duplicates code on all worksheets apart from named worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which removes rows from 'ACHAL' worksheet where a match is found between column M and Column A of 'Archive' worksheet.

I need to run the same script for all worksheets but, my workbook is made up of several worksheets where the worksheet names will frequently change; so I do not want to add the worksheet names to the code.

Within the workbook I have 2 worksheets that have a constant worksheet name (these will not change) and the code needs to run on all worksheets apart from 'All Data' and 'Archive'.

Is there a way of looping the code so it runs on all worksheets apart from 'All Data' and 'Archive'. The code will need to stop after it has run on the last worksheet.

```
Sub ArchiveMatch()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("ACHAL")
        LR = .Range("M2:M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = LR To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Archive").Columns("A"), 0)) Then .Rows(i).Delete
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through all sheets, then check that the current sheet isn't All Data or Archive like so:

```
Sub ArchiveMatch()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "All Data" And sh.Name <> "Archive" Then
            LR = sh.Range("M2:M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = LR To 1 Step -1
                If IsNumeric(Application.Match(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Archive").Columns("A"), 0)) Then sh.Rows(i).Delete
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect ... thank you. Made a slight adjustment to skip the first row (title row) ... it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in all the sheets with this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Activate
    Next
End Sub
```

If you have an exception for one or more sheets, compare with this `Sheets(i).Name`

Hope it works.

Comment: Many thanks ... I have more code to script that needs to applied for all worksheets, this will be very useful.